# Custom Post Type Pagination on Single.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

The same old problem and not sure if its even possible.

Pagination on a single.php custom post type, is it possible?

This works fine until i turn permalinks to /%postname%/ then it just reloads the same page when click on the previous/next links,

```
<?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=1&orderby&menu_order&post_type=press-round'.'&paged='.$paged); 

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>


  <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav>
<?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
<?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</nav>

<?php $wp_query = null;  $wp_query = $temp;?>
```

I've refreshed the permalinks, removed the htaccess, made sure a page is not the same name everything that you'd usually do.

Is it just not possible to have permalinks on for pagination on a single custom post type page?

Comment: I would use a plugin like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ or you can use your own function like the one here http://wp-snippets.com/pagination-without-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using `next_posts_link()` etc... note the plural form 'posts'.

To link to previous and next single posts you need to use `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()`.

Basically change 'posts' to 'post' in the function names.

Comment: +1. Also: what is the need for the custom query? It's [not necessary for displaying the single-post page for a custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display). WordPress handles custom post type queries out-of-the-box.

Comment: No worries, easily done :)